# Would low resolution and high resolution images have same quality if resized to the same shape?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

We're working on a computer vision project and we got two datasets, one in a high-resolution format (e.g. shape=2540, 1780) and a lower-resolution version (e.g. shape=1270, 890). Since images have to be resized for the CNN, both will be resized to a small size of say (846, 593). In the end, the resize through some pixel values away.

W**ould we end up with the same resized image in both cases since we're resizing to a smaller size?**

Note: Yes we can scale the CNN to higher dimension input, but just asking to compare whether resizing to a smaller size will lead to the same results?

If interpolation is used while resizing the image even to a smaller size. Assume that in a low-quality image we want to resize 18x18 pixels into 3x3 pixels so we interpolate each 6x6 into 1 pixel so we have information from the 6x6 grid. While in the high-resolution version we resize say 36x36 pixels into a 3x3 pixel grid so basically we're getting information from 12x12 into 1-pixel value. So if the interpolation is efficient, the more information, the better. But if the interpolation is inefficient, we'll lose much information from converting the 12x12 pixel grid into a 1-pixel value, in this case, the lower resolution seems to be a better choice. I'm confused

Comment: By using resize function, you ll lose the accuracy so solutions will be affected. You can get better results or you may not. But simply answer is no, the images dont have the same quality

Comment: It depends entirely on your planned application. The expected difference would probably be very small, but there will definitely be one and for some applications it might make a difference. This question is unfortunately not clear enough without more background or a precise definition of image quality.

Comment: "I'm confused." Just try it out. Do both and compare the results. If they are different, use the one from the better resolution, if not, it's your choice.